# How to copy the new browser structure panel?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I want to create a complete copy of the panel for the structure of the model, but I do not know how to achieve this. They will be very grateful if you tell me how to create a complete copy of this panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an exact copy of the model structure panel, you can do it like so:

```
const panel = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerModelStructurePanel(viewer, 'MyModelStructurePanel');
panel.addModel(viewer.model);
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am also interested in where can I find the source of this panel?

Comment: You're welcome Alisa. Typically the code would be available in the [API reference](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference). Unfortunately this class is not documented there as it's not officially part of the public APIs, so you'd need to look at the Forge Viewer [JavaScript source](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js) and search for something like `function ViewerModelStructurePanel`.